# Create JSON object dynamically from a form custom attributes

Tags: javascript, json

What is the best way to parse through each input on a form to produce the Json object below? I am not married to the custom Attributes, if the is a better simpler way please share it.

```
   <form>   
    <label>Address</label>

       <input type="text" name="address" data-label="Address" data-group="partcipantInfo" data-column="dataBaseAddress" data-internalUse="1" data-userDefined="0" value="123 Acme Way"/>


     <label>City</label>

          <input type="text" name="City" data-label="City" data-group="partcipantInfo" data-column="dataBaseCity" data-internalUse="1" data-userDefined="1" value="Loony Tunes"/>

   <input type="submit"value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Trying to get this result for each

```
{
   "inputs":[
      {
         "DataLabel":"Address",
         "DataGroup":"Address on Record",
         "DataColumn":"DataBaseAddress",
         "Value":"123 Acme Way",
         "InternalUse":true,
         "userDefined":false
      },
      {
         "DataLabel":null,
         "DataGroup":"Address on Record",
         "DataColumn":"dataBaseCity",
         "Value":"Loony Tunes",
         "InternalUse":true,
         "userDefined":true
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the jQuery serializeArray() method:

```
var jsonData = $("form").serializeArray();
```

For more info:

```
http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/
```

Answer (score 0):

Fairly simple:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
var obj = {
  inputs : Array.prototype.map.call(inputs, function(input){
    return {
      DataLabel : input.getAttribute('data-label'),
      DataGroup : input.getAttribute('data-group'),
      DataColumn : input.getAttribute('data-column'),
      Value: input.value,
      InternalUse: !!+input.getAttribute('data-internalUse'),
      userDefined: !!+input.getAttribute('data-userDefined')
    }
  })
}

console.log(obj);
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/casazame/1/edit

Note: `!!+` is a short way of converting `'0'/'1'` to `false/true`.